# perl extract information from several files in folders into the specific files

Tags: perl, extract

I'm just trying to extract of daily data to analyze yearly something.

So, I made a code for searching folder and files.

After that I wanna extract curtain lines in several files that has same name in the middle.

When I done my work, I realize that there are only one day information left

daily data is grid format like this.

```
ncols           751
nrows           601
xllcorner       124.5
yllcorner       33.
cellsize        0.01
nodata_value    -99
 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0
```

I wanna get the result like this with my code.

```
1.txt (2011)
10 10 10 10 10 4 4 3 2
5 4 3 2 10 4 4 3 2
1 1 10 10 10 10 10 10

2.txt (2012)
3 4 2 10 10 4 4 3 2
5 4 3 2 10 4 4 3 2
1 1 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

---

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;

if( $#ARGV < 0 )
  { die "need folder.\n"; }

$dirName = shift(@ARGV);
local($i);

#rutine 
&readSubDir($dirName);

sub readSubDir 
{
    if(!opendir(dirHandle, $_[0]))
    {
        print "$_[0] Failed opening.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    local(@files) = readdir(dirHandle);

    local($i);
    local($newFile);

    local(@dironly);
    local(@fileonly);

    for($i = 0; $i <= $#files; $i++)
    {
        $newFile = $_[0]."\\".$files[$i];
        if(-d $newFile)
        {
        push(@dironly, $files[$i]);
        }
        elsif(-f $newFile)
        {
            push(@fileonly, $files[$i]);
        }
        else
        {}
    }

    @files = @dironly;
    push(@files, @fileonly);
    closedir dirHandle;


    my $cnt = 1;
    my $b = 2011;

    for($i =0; $i <= $#files; $i++){
        $newFile = $_[0]."\\".$files[$i];
        if(-f $newFile){
        open(fileHandle, $newFile)|| die "Cannot open 개체 \n";
        my($dir, $file, $ext) = ($newFile =~ m|^(.*\\)(.*)(\..*)$| );
        if (substr($file,17,4) eq $b){
        while(<fileHandle>){
            if($. == 7){        
        my $filename = $cnt.'.txt';
        open OUT, ">$filename" or die "Failed to create $filename";
        print OUT $_;
        }
        }
        close(fileHandle);
        }
        elsif (substr($file,17,4) eq $b+1){
        $b++;
        $cnt++;
        while(<fileHandle>){
            if($. == 7){        
        my $filename = $cnt.'.txt';
        open OUT, ">$filename" or die "Failed to create $filename";
        print OUT $_;
        }
        }
        close(fileHandle);
        }
        }
        close(OUT);
        }
}
```

Comment: Always `use strict` in your scripts. And you should use the three-argument-version of `open` like `open my $fh , '>' , $filename or die "Failed to create $filename: $!" ;`. And try to use proper indention that will help you and others to read your scripts more easily.

Comment: And limit the scope of your variables to the neccessary parts. So don't write `local($i);` at the top of your script. When you need that variable just write `for( my $i = 0 ; $i <= $#files ; $i++ ) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

The question really isn't clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish, as the information in the daily file data example doesn't match any of the data in the output examples.  However, from looking at your code I think I get what you're trying to do and I think your problem is occurring when you open the output file to store the lines you extracted.  You're opening the file with **>**, which indicates you're opening the file for output, but it will also overwrite the file if it already exists.  So your code is just overwriting the same file over and over and only the information in the last file will be saved.  You need to open the file in append mode using **>>**. So your code should look similar to the following:

```
 open OUT, ">>$filename" or die "Failed to create $filename";
```

Comment: Thank you. I can get proper results with your comments.

Comment: You should use the three-argument-version of open like `open my $fh , '>>' , $filename or die "Failed to append to $filename: $!" ;`.